# React Navigation bottomTabNavigator "createRouter is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have created a stackNavigator(for login signup screens) that's working perfectly and then after that I created bottomTabsNavigator but for some reason I am getting this error "Create Router is not a function" check screenshot below:

[image: Error Image]

Here is my code:

```js
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

/** Bottom tab navigator */
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MyTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Tab1">
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component={Tab1} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" component={Tab2} />
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <MyTabs />
        </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

I did exactly what React Navigation 5.x docs recommended but still I faced this issue. Let me know if someone faced something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just resolved the issue here.

I updated to the last version of all libs

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.1",
"@react-navigation/core": "^5.1.0",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.0.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.1",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.1",
```

and then i deleted my package-lock.json,

and in your terminal go to android folder and then type ./gradlew clean

after that you should run your npx react-native run-android,

close your default metro terminal,

and then run npx react-native start --reset-cache,

worked well after doing this

Comment: I did the same and was about to write this exact same answer for others. I installed everything that was mentioned in the guide again and it worked. Maybe I missed something the first time which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed latest versions of `@react-navigation/native` and `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`:

```js
npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
```

Then clear the cache:

```sh
npm react-native start --reset-cache
```

Or if using Expo:

```js
expo start -c
```